# network map drive not accessible

Tags: network-drive

I am having a VC++ exe which calls network map drive with alphabet name "M" (M: \server-ip\sharename). Based on the business, it copies some files to the network shared folder and it is working fine.

The problem is, when I call VC++ exe from .NET application using Process.Start(startInfo) the network map drive is throwing exception saying netwrok not found.

In some user PCs  it is working fine even called from .net app. We are using .NET framework 3.5 with sp1 and OS is XP. Please help me in resolving this. I tried even CASPOL.exe to give the full trust to network share.

Comment: Can you post the code? Maybe there's a bug there

Comment: Code to call the exe...string strCommand = "VC.exe"; System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + strCommand); procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo; proc.Start();   It is working fine in some PCs and not working in some..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting your VC++ EXE you could start a command shell (cmd.exe) and look for yourself if the network drive exists.

If not it I'd look which user context your program and the cmd.exe are running under and make sure it is the same user and this user has the network drive.